# 1.5 year old daughter is afraid of strangers

Tags: infant, crying

My daughter who is 1.5 years old is afraid of strangers. I thought its normal. But she is crying when she meet anyone whom she is not familiar with. Is it normal? I took her to a nearby nursery school. She is interacting with other kids there without any problem. Took her to super market and mostly to all public places I go. She is ok and not showing any issues. Only when someone tries to talk she is crying and making noice. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: yea it's pretty normal. 
Usually around 4/5 it completely end but until then kids have periods like this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kids of this age can take time to interact normally with new faces, its okay, let her take time. Meanwhile continue to take her places, introduce her to uncles, aunts and neighbors. The moment she cries, withdraw, do not force her to meet and say hello.
In fact, you can begin meeting a new person for her, exchange pleasantries and spend time with that person in her presence, this might comfort her and she may develop acceptance for that new person in life.

However, do not rush things, hope this helps you!

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty common, and she will naturally grow out of it with time.  It's not usually something you need to be worried about.  The only possible problem is that it may be slightly harder to pass her off to a babysitter or care giver until she has started trusting adults more.

While you don't need to change her, and should not force anything on her if she clearly isn't uncomfortable, there are a few things you can do to make her a little more comfortable with other adults while she grows into being comfortable with adult interaction.

**Hold her when she is meeting adults**

Kids are tiny, and adults are by comparison huge.  Simply holding your daughter so she is eye level with an adult speaking to her will prevent the adult from looming over her, while at the same time helping assure her that you have and will take care of her.  She likely will be more open to interactions from adults while held in your arms and feeling safe.

**Act as an intermediary between adult and daughter**

If she is crying when the adults talk to her let the adults talk to you and then you relay the question to your daughter.  Depending on the source of the anxiety you may be able to greatly lower her discomfort just by having the adult not focused on her personally.

**Give her the ability to opt out of interactions that aren't important**

Some kids are naturally introverted or shy.  They may not fear an adult in general, but they may be uncomfortable being forced to directly interact with them.  Many times there is no real need to do so, so respect the child's right to avoid unpleasant interaction with an adult without her needing to cry.  You want to avoid unpleasant interactions so she will focus on the positive interactions.  Which means...

**Give her adults she will have a positive experience with**

Let her meet adults that will be fun and she is likely to enjoy interacting with, in a controlled setting with you nearby for comfort if she needs it of course.  There are adults out there who have experience with kids and can usually get a child to open up to them enough to get them playing.  By letting her meet adults she actually enjoys interaction with you will encourage her to see that new interactions are not always bad and that it's okay to give an adult a chance.

If you don't know how to get her to trust another adult long enough to interact with them in a positive manner I have a whole [list](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/40877/how-to-tell-to-my-4-years-daughter-that-she-should-not-to-be-scared-of-a-specifi/40881#40881) of suggestions on that specifically.